# How to avoid superbrick by flashing / modding / rooting?

Tags: unbricking

How is a superbrick accomplished? I am looking for advice of things to avoid and list of causes.

Such as, what if I accidentally flashed the wrong recovery? Could this result in a superbrick?

Or if I accidentally flashed the recovery into the wrong mount point / block device.

Or if power is lost during flashing?

Superbrick for the sake of this question is defined as resulting the phone getting into a state that can no longer be repaired by usual flashing. When the manufacturer service would be required to physically swap components, soldering etc.

Comment: Best way to absolutely avoid a "superbrick"? Don't unlock the bootloader or flash anything... if it is that important to you that you can't possibly risk a total brick condition, don't try anything. The second best way, get a Nexus device, it is virtually impossible to superbrick a Nexus device, you can flash just about (anything except the wrong bootloader, which it shouldn't accept anyway), mess up the kernel, wipe the entire system partition, or even flash a ROM for a different device, and a Nexus device can recover

Comment: A phone can have e.g. 20 partitions. Only about 5 of those are used by Android proper, the rest are from your device OEM. Messing with any of those other partitions can hardbrick you, depending on the manufacturer. The best tool for flashing is fastboot because it doesn't allow for any of those non-standard partitions to be flashed. That is the real reason people think Nexus is more robust.

Answer (score 0):

1) Flashing the wrong recovery will not result in a hard brick.

2) Flashing a recovery to the wrong mount point *might* result in a hard brick, depending on which point you flash it to. If you flashed it to the bootloader mount point, well, then, the MB is toast.

3) If power is lost during flashing, it's *probably* still okay unless you were flashing the bootloader.

**The things to avoid are:**

A) `fastboot erase bootloader` <-- Why does this command even exist???

B) Flashing the wrong bootloader (most of the time the device will reject it if it's not made for it anyway)

C) Flashing the wrong radio

D) Doing stupid things with root

Comment: technically point 2 counters point 1. If you get the wrong recovery and it is too large you can overwrite other partitions. Also flashing partition tables (e.g. wrong PIT file on Samsung) can hardbrick you.